# GWTEventService push to all clients

Tags: java, events, gwt, gwt-eventservice

I can't figure out how to get an EventExecutor that pushes to all clients instead of only one. I found the passage in the manual which states I can get the required functionality on server side by `EventExecutorServiceFactory.getInstance().getEventExecutorService(String)` which unfortunately requires a user ID. I tried providing an empty string or null without success. So how do you go about sending an event to all listening clients?

Comment: `EventExecutorServiceFactory` isn't a class in GWT - where are you getting that from (and can you add that as a tag so that experts in that lib will see it)?

Comment: This Class is from GWTEventService lib (see title). Unfortunately there appears to be no tag for that lib and I lack the 150 rep to create one. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On server-side, you can either:

- extend the `RemoteEventServiceServlet` (if you can/you are allowed to);
- use an in-process `EventExecutorService`.

In the first case you already have an `addEvent()` method available right in the servlet, in the second case, you need to instantiate the executor service via:

```
EventExecutorServiceFactory factory =
    EventExecutorServiceFactory.getInstance();
EventExecutorService service =
    factory.getEventExecutorService(httpServletRequest)
```

Where `httpServletRequest` is the current http request (e.g., retrieve it using `getThreadLocalRequest()` in a RPC-based servlet).

The point is that you need to define your *domain(s)* in which events will be published. Then you can freely use `addEvent(yourDomain, yourEvent)` (from your servlet, or from the executor) to send your event to all available clients that are listening to such event.

In other words events are always broadcasted to all available clients registered on a specific *domain*. If you want to send an event to a specific client, then use `DomainFactory.USER_SPECIFIC_DOMAIN` as domain.

P.S. You will probably have more visibility if you ask directly to the [group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gwteventservice) or the [forum](http://gwteventservice.freeforums.org/).

Comment: Is there any reason not to convert all my `RemoteServiceServlets` to `RemoteEventServiceServlets`?